# Выбрать определенный элемент селектором css

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите css селектор, чтобы выбрать все ссылки, кроме первой ("Страница 1"). Html структуру менять нельзя.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <span>
        <span>
          <a href="#">Страница 1</a> »
          <span>
            <a href="#">Страница 2</a> »
            <span>
              <a href="#">Страница 3</a> »
              <span class="last">Текущая</span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор элементов `a`, для которых родительским элементом (>) является `span`, которому предшествует (~) элемент `a`

```css
a~span>a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <span>
        <span>
          <a href="#">Страница 1</a> »
          <span>
            <a href="#">Страница 2</a> »
            <span>
              <a href="#">Страница 3</a> »
              <span class="last">Текущая</span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!